# Repeat breakout rooms from one Zoom meeting to another

Tags: zoom.us

Suppose I host a regular Zoom meeting with the same people, such as an online class. Is there a way to have Zoom assign them the same breakout rooms that were used at the previous meeting? I know [how to preassign breakout rooms](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360032752671-Pre-assigning-participants-to-breakout-rooms), but I don't know how to make Zoom output the list of breakout rooms that were used in a way suitable for preassigning the next time.